# Reference for closed map lemma

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I would like to have a reference (book, page) for the following version of the closed map lemma:

If a continuous function between locally compact Hausdorff spaces is proper (i.e. preimages of compact sets are compact), then it is also closed.

Comment: Only $Y$, the codomain, is required to be locally compact Hausdorff. I know how the proof goes, but I don't know a reference.

Comment: A continuous function between locally compact Hausdorff spaces extends continuously to the Alexandrov compactifications iff it is proper. A subset $A$ of a locally compact Hausdorff space is closed iff $A \cup \{\infty\}$ is closed in the Alexandrov compactification. Should be covered in more or less every book on point-set topology.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can find this in Munkres' Topology, but I don't have the page number off the top of my head.

Comment: @Daniel: It isn’t. It’s implicit in an easy generalization of one late exercise in the first edition of Munkres; I don’t see it in Willard or Engelking at all.

Comment: @Brian Still, it _should_ be, IMO;) Gilles, if you're happy with an out-of-print German book, it's theorem 8.25 (p. 90) in Boto v. Querenburg, Mengentheoretische Topologie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure there are many other proofs in print, but one place you can find it is Theorem 4.95 in my book *[Introduction to Topological Manifolds](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-1-4419-7939-1)* (2nd edition).  I state and prove it there for maps into compactly generated Hausdorff spaces, and Lemma 4.94 just above shows that all locally compact spaces are compactly generated.

Answer (score 3):

For a precise statement and a proof thereof, see Theorem 2.6 of [this paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/fundthmalg/propermaps.pdf).